# Python Selenium Get multiple images with the same class and save it

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, bots

So, i want to create a bot that downloads multiple (All) memes on Reddit (the Class for the images is _2_tDEnGMLxpM6uOa2kaDB3 ImageBox-image media-element _1XWObl-3b9tPy64oaG6fax)

Okay, here is my Code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pyautogui
import urllib
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
browser.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/memes/new/')
time.sleep(3)
pyautogui.click(375,187)
findclass = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("_2_tDEnGMLxpM6uOa2kaDB3 ImageBox-image media-element _1XWObl-3b9tPy64oaG6fax")
for i in findclass:
    try:
        src = findclass.get_attribute('src')
        urllib.urlretrieve(src, "meme.png")
        print("found it!")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

In my Output is NOTHING, no error nothing idk what went wrong xd ???

Comment: Have you tried installing just one? Start small, it might not be seeing the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean to get all the src tags? Also added how to use notifications for the allow/block part.

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

# Pass the argument 1 to allow and 2 to block
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", { 
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1 
})
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe",options=options)
browser.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/memes/new/')
elems=[link.get_attribute("src")for link in browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//img[contains(@class,'ImageBox-image')]")]
print(elems)
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
```

Output:

```
['https://preview.redd.it/4g91j26pdzc61.jpg?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=df817665333696fa9d3bc61c648f436c7d4866cc', 'https://external-preview.redd.it/tTv773TGtaaR1SZje-nRpxTMJqU4etx426sLNbbnPHI.jpg?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=60be46511f8dc95ba81cc196ef8a4127eed8cf2e', 'https://preview.redd.it/q6fpcqgldzc61.jpg?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=c1376540801c30af074f08df96d2c30b3f0f0b53', 'https://preview.redd.it/risq0ndndzc61.jpg?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=14297374d2ce1a5cdd757e7003ecad159abca345', 'https://preview.redd.it/e3ak8tzldzc61.jpg?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=155d24158cf009988411013d0759f48da1034a53', 'https://preview.redd.it/vpkai4wkdzc61.jpg?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=c01eb9e610fb228b5b3a72bdb9b4e2b61b2e2835', 'https://i.redd.it/ymtqptejdzc61.jpg', 'https://preview.redd.it/0hx2vjmgdzc61.jpg?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=ca24c436b8c9d9b1fba04c3dc5749b9a34e319fb', 'https://preview.redd.it/untwq4iddzc61.jpg?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=b2de8dafda5359946ce35d7acc35c0ba50af0b46']
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks For the Anwser That is what i need Thanks for adding the Notifications part xd! But is there a way to filter out the ads? There is a badge at the ads with the class_2oEYZXchPfHwcf9mTMGMg8 its a span. So is there a way to make a if and say something like if the class is with the image : dont get src.

Comment: If link.get_attribute("class") != "whatever" :  in front of the link. You could probably make the xpath more focused

Comment: If the links are only in divs just add //div/img and the span/img ones will go.